# How can I achieve pivot table output in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

If I have a MySQL table looking something like this:

[image: A sample data]

How to write a mysql query to get output like this:

```
userid        total_entries      products_sold
------------------------------------------------------------------
204           1011               1500
195           785                350
```

The idea is that we want to get total entries and sum of products sold per user. I'm not sure if this is called a pivot table but someone suggested that? Help me to write mysql query and if there is also date in the column and we want to get entries for today.

Comment: "Pivot" is the right database concept. To pull this off with your table it would look like: `SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as total_entries, SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'products_sold' THEN (value * 1) END as products_sold FROM yourtable GROUP BY userid;`

Comment: Thanks for reply JNevill, But in my case, userid is not a column. I am not able to group on this field.

Comment: Gotcha. Probably makes sense to use that same `CASE` logic then for userid assuming that the first column (`sid`?) is 1:1 with a `userid`. `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'userid' THEN (value*1) END as userid, ...` This is one of the downsides of an EAV design; your SQL tends to get ugly.

Comment: What version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.29

Answer (score 0):

You could do self-joins for each attribute. I'm guessing a bit at this, because your example data doesn't match the result you show.

```
SELECT u.value AS userid,
  t.value AS total_entries,
  s.value AS products_sold
FROM mytable AS u
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t USING (sid)
LEFT JOIN mytable AS s USING (sid)
WHERE u.name='userid'
  AND t.name='total_entries'
  AND s.name='products_sold';
```